# Unable to see null values in left join MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have 2 tables that I need to join but for some reason I am not getting the expected result.

Table 1 has all dates of the year and table 2 has data for some dates. I have the following:

**Table 1**

```
+------------+
|   dates    |
+------------+
| 2016-11-01 |
| 2016-11-02 |
| 2016-11-03 |
| 2016-11-04 |
| 2016-11-05 |
| 2016-11-06 |
| 2016-11-07 |
| 2016-11-08 |
| 2016-11-09 |
| 2016-11-10 |
+------------+
```

**Table 2**

```
+------------+--------+----+
|   dates    | status | id |
+------------+--------+----+
| 2016-11-01 |      1 |  1 |
| 2016-11-02 |      1 |  1 |
| 2016-11-03 |      1 |  1 |
| 2016-11-04 |      1 |  2 |
| 2016-11-05 |      1 |  2 |
| 2016-11-06 |      1 |  2 |
| 2016-11-07 |      1 |  1 |
| 2016-11-08 |      1 |  2 |
| 2016-11-09 |      1 |  1 |
| 2016-11-10 |      1 |  1 |
+------------+--------+----+
```

**Expected result**

```
+------------+--------+
|   dates    | Status |
+------------+--------+
| 2016-11-01 | 1      |
| 2016-11-02 | 1      |
| 2016-11-03 | 1      |
| 2016-11-04 | null   |
| 2016-11-05 | null   |
| 2016-11-06 | null   |
| 2016-11-07 | 1      |
| 2016-11-08 | null   |
| 2016-11-09 | 1      |
| 2016-11-10 | 1      |
+------------+--------+
```

**Current Result:**

```
+------------+--------+
|   dates    | status |
+------------+--------+
| 2016-11-01 |      1 |
| 2016-11-02 |      1 |
| 2016-11-03 |      1 |
| 2016-11-07 |      1 |
| 2016-11-09 |      1 |
| 2016-11-10 |      1 |
+------------+--------+
```

this is the query I am currently using:

```
select 
    a.dates,
    b.status
from table1 a 
left join table2 b on a.dates = b.dates
where b.id = 1;
```

Unfortunately it only shows data where the id is 1 and skips the null values. I need to see the null values too. What I am doing wrong???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the `b.id = 1` criterion from the `where` clause to the join condition because the `where` clause applies to the entire resultset **after** the join:

```
select 
    a.dates,
    b.status
from table1 a 
left join table2 b on a.dates = b.dates and b.id = 1
```

Comment: Dear God you are right...!!! you just saved my life my friend...!!! thanks

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
select 
    a.dates,
    b.status
from table1 a 
left join table2 b on a.dates = b.dates AND b.id = 1
;
```

in your version you get only the results where b.id = 1